# Hibernate selecting from multiple mapped entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to figure out how Hibernate handles the following situation:

Say I have entities A, and B properly mapped in an hbm file. If I write an HQL query the selects from both of them (e.g. `from A, B where ...`) what is returned? I assume it cannot be cast to either the object representing A, or B since it is some combination of these two.

Comment: Why don't you simply test it?

Answer (score 0):

In fact what you're trying to do is called a projection. Hibernate all by itself will return a List (untyped) of all the beans that are returned by your query. If you;re using the JPA implementation, you can actually decalre a Class which would contain the aggregated values of the results you're getting back, something like this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
```

name="DepartmentSummary",
entities={
@EntityResult(entityClass=Department.class,
fields=@FieldResult(name="name", column="DEPT_NAME")),
@EntityResult(entityClass=Employee.class)
},
columns={@ColumnResult(name="TOT_EMP"),
@ColumnResult(name="AVG_SAL")}
)